# Credential Response Parameter not received Google Auth Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-signin, google-authentication

I am trying to create a "sign in with google" feature to my localhost website. Im receiving the POST request but it doesn't have the `credential` parameter. Im not sure if there is something with the code or the API configuration in Google Cloud Platform.

Here is some code:

signup.ejs :

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
                <div id="g_id_onload"
                    data-client_id="1015192592170-ab5cf8pmhsse8tgblsjgvaiu8fkh5614.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                    data-context="signup"
                    data-ux_mode="redirect"
                    data-login_uri="http://localhost:3002/auth/google/callback"
                    data-auto_prompt="false">
                </div>

                <div class="g_id_signin"
                    data-type="standard"
                    data-shape="pill"
                    data-theme="filled_blue"
                    data-text="signup_with"
                    data-size="large"
                    data-logo_alignment="left">
                </div>
```

main.js (express server-side) :

```
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const client = new OAuth2Client("1015192592170-ab5cf8pmhsse8tgblsjgvaiu8fkh5614.apps.googleusercontent.com");

... 

app.post('/auth/google/callback', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.cookies.g_csrf_token)
    console.log(req)

    async function verify() {
        const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: req.cookies.g_csrf_token,
            audience: "1015192592170-ab5cf8pmhsse8tgblsjgvaiu8fkh5614.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        });
        const payload = ticket.getPayload();
        const userid = payload['sub'];
      }
      verify().catch(console.error);
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

console.log(req) :

```
<ref *2> IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: false,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: true,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
  },
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { end: [Function: clearRequestTimeout] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Function: socketOnError],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 2,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3002',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 4
    },
    _server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 2,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3002',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 4
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': [Function: bound setRequestTimeout],
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '2': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '3': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '4': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '5': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      '6': [Function: bound onParserTimeout],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular *1],
      incoming: [Circular *2],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      [Symbol(resource_symbol)]: [HTTPServerAsyncResource]
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: ServerResponse {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: false,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: true,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: false,
      _headerSent: false,
      socket: [Circular *1],
      _header: null,
      _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
      _sent100: false,
      _expect_continue: false,
      req: [Circular *2],
      locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 145,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
  },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: {
    host: 'localhost:3002',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-length': '1323',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="92", "Opera GX";v="78"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    origin: 'null',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36 OPR/78.0.4093.186',
    accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    cookie: 'g_csrf_token=beb9e4ae1c0ea1a6'
  },
  rawHeaders: [
    'Host',
    'localhost:3002',
    'Connection',
    'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length',
    '1323',
    'Cache-Control',
    'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua',
    '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="92", "Opera GX";v="78"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile',
    '?0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests',
    '1',
    'Origin',
    'null',
    'Content-Type',
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36 OPR/78.0.4093.186',
    'Accept',
    'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site',
    'cross-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode',
    'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User',
    '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest',
    'document',
    'Accept-Encoding',
    'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language',
    'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Cookie',
    'g_csrf_token=beb9e4ae1c0ea1a6'
  ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  aborted: false,
  upgrade: false,
  url: '/auth/google/callback',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  statusMessage: null,
  client: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Function: socketOnError],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 2,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3002',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 4
    },
    _server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 2,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3002',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 4
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': [Function: bound setRequestTimeout],
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '2': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '3': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '4': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '5': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      '6': [Function: bound onParserTimeout],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular *1],
      incoming: [Circular *2],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      [Symbol(resource_symbol)]: [HTTPServerAsyncResource]
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: ServerResponse {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: false,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: true,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: false,
      _headerSent: false,
      socket: [Circular *1],
      _header: null,
      _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
      _sent100: false,
      _expect_continue: false,
      req: [Circular *2],
      locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 145,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
  },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  next: [Function: next],
  baseUrl: '',
  originalUrl: '/auth/google/callback',
  _parsedUrl: Url {
    protocol: null,
    slashes: null,
    auth: null,
    host: null,
    port: null,
    hostname: null,
    hash: null,
    search: null,
    query: null,
    pathname: '/auth/google/callback',
    path: '/auth/google/callback',
    href: '/auth/google/callback',
    _raw: '/auth/google/callback'
  },
  params: {},
  query: {},
  res: <ref *3> ServerResponse {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: true,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: false,
    _headerSent: false,
    socket: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *3],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 145,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: null,
    _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
    _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
    _sent100: false,
    _expect_continue: false,
    req: [Circular *2],
    locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] { 'x-powered-by': [Array] }
  },
  secret: undefined,
  cookies: { g_csrf_token: 'beb9e4ae1c0ea1a6' },
  signedCookies: [Object: null prototype] {},
  route: Route {
    path: '/auth/google/callback',
    stack: [ [Layer] ],
    methods: { post: true }
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
}
```

I know i am not supposed to be using the csrf token for `verifyIdToken` but i couldn't find the credential response.

Here is the OAuth Client Data:

[image: This is the OAuth Client data]

Comment: Hi @harook_tk, 
Fast forward to 2023, did you get the solution to your original query? 
I am facing the same issue. Not getting `credential` key in request as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @ParthMistry I havent worked on that project in a while, let me check and let you know.

Comment: @ParthMistry I'm not really sure what I did to fix it. I'll just some of the main code here and you try trial and error. So sorry about this. I need to start using git from now on so that I can see what changes I've made lmao.

Comment: @ParthMistry email me or tag me here if u want to have a look at the whole file or if you have any other questions : haroontk14@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

@parthMistry

signup.ejs

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
                <div id="g_id_onload"
                    data-client_id="1015192592170-ab5cf8pmhsse8tgblsjgvaiu8fkh5614.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                    data-login_uri="http://localhost:3002/auth/google/callback"
                    data-auto_prompt="false">
                </div>
                <div class="g_id_signin"
                    data-type="standard"
                    data-size="large"
                    data-theme="outline"
                    data-text="sign_in_with"
                    data-shape="pill"
                    data-logo_alignment="left">
                </div>
```

google.js (file connected to main.js on express server-side)

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();

const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;

const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const client = new OAuth2Client(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);


router.post('/callback', (req, res) => {

    async function verify() {
        const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: req.body.credential,
            audience: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        });
        const payload = ticket.getPayload();
        const userid = payload['sub'];

        console.log(payload)
    }
    verify().catch(console.error);

    res.sendStatus(200)
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hi @haroon_tk,     
I have the same backend/frontend setup. But that dont work consistently. 
Thru trial and error on my project, I found that when I run my project on one port lets say 8090, the backend callback dont have the `credential` key. But when I run the same project on another port say 3030, it have the `credential` key in request. 

Settings for both the port are same in Google's OAuth Client dashboard. 
Very weird but no idea what to do. Tried this only on localhost yet. Haven't checked with any published site yet.

Comment: @ParthMistry I'm not sure then. I don't think I ran into that type of error when I was coding. I would suggest reading Google's documentation and making changes on the google dashboard.

It might have something to do with the callback link you specified on Google's dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The encoded JWT is contained in the `credential` request parameter of the POST response. For CSRF both a cookie and a request parameter are included.

In your example above you are clearly able to fetch and use the cookie from the POST response, to use the JWT you'll just need to reference the request parameter. Your logging does not include request parameters by the way, only the cookies.

The format of the POST response is described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference?hl=en#id-token-handler-endpoint).